# How to put two node.js chaincodes in the same folder

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I would like to know how to have two chaincode scripts written in node.js in the same folder.
I'm using the fabcar network, I basically made a copy of the fabcar chaincode, renamed it fabbus, changed its initial values, installed/instantiated it, etc...
It worked really fine when I just put one chaincode per folder, but I feel like it's not the right way to do it.
When trying to put the two scripts in the same folder, there's already something fishy :

[fabcar folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8OB7.png)

There's only one package and it's the one of fabcar.js !
It doesn't work and it seems like the problem come from here.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLRjF.png)

How can I remedy to this problem ?
Does defining every type of vehicle in one chaincode is a better solution ? Most likely this network will evolve post-deployment to add more type of vehicles with different attributes, etc.
Inexperienced as I am, what are your advices ?

Comment: It would be helpful to add a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful to include the error message as text (not as picture).

Comment: Thanks for your advices, i'll apply them next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaincodes in Hyperledger Fabric usually reside in their own folders, so you can always install+instantiate+use a second chaincode residing in a separate folder. If you feel like you need to update a specific chaincode  with more feature, instead of installing a separate chaincode---one option is to [upgrade the existing chaincode](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/chaincode4noah.html#upgrade) with the new source code.

Comment: I think I'll use the only-one-chaincode solution. Thanks for your answer ! :)